# how to build big size parity check matix?

Tags: coding-theory

I want to do a project and I need to have a parity check matrix for LDPC code which has big size ( for example in size $400 \times400 $). please tell me how can I build a matrix with this size.

Comment: If the parity check matrix is square, then the code is trivial.

Comment: I want to have a LDCP code with a big size parity check matrix and if I want to build that code I have to have that matrix.tell me which structure I have to use to build that matrix

Comment: Might be better asked at http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: The simplest construction is to pick a low value $j \approx 3$, then create a random $r \times n$ matrix where each position is $1$ with probability $j/r$ and $0$ with probability $1-j/r$. For large $n$, the code should have rate $\approx 1-r/n$. If you want a *regular* LDPC code, you can then go through the matrix row-by-row to satisfy the constant row-weight and constant column-weight requirements.